# Signal double ratchet only giving "weak" forward secrecy?

Tags: forward-secrecy, signal-protocol

I was just watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSMqfPCM6_4&t=537s) on the Double ratcheting protocol.

at around 31:37, the presenter says that the protocol only provides weak forward secrecy.

I've only ever heard about a distinction between Perfect forward secrecy, and "normal" forward secrecy. Where the perfect version is resistant to leakage of long term keys,

So I don't really understand in which way the double ratchet procedure only has weak forward secrecy. Can someone explain to me how this is the case?

Best regards

Comment: The term 'weak forward secrecy' is mentioned in the [Noise Protocol Framework](https://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html) spec. It's also described on [Noise Explorer](https://noiseexplorer.com/patterns/IK/).